# Problem in establishing connection between power BI and AWS EC2 hosted MySQL database which has SSH tunneling

Tags: mysql, amazon-ec2, ssh, powerbi

I tried connecting my EC2 server MySQL database with power BI[image: I have selected the Get data ->My SQL database and gave the SSH hostname:port ,with MySQL username and password]

Here i got "Unable to connect to host error"

Second method i tried i have forwarded the data to my local port using SSH tunneling command  and tried connecting the power BI with the local host and port number.But still I got the error as "Reading data from stream failed" in Power BI.

Can anyone suggest me how to get the data in power BI from the SSH EC2 hosted mySQL database.